# not enough that I thought I should be(to express quantity)

Tags: phrases, expressions

Could you please tell me if my answer is correct, and is this a set/fix phrase?

Q:do you exercise?

### A:well, **not enough that I thought I should be.**

(What I mean to say is, I do exercise, but its not enough from what I think I should have, to answer someone stating the quantity of exercise.)

Thx.

Comment: Probably _not as much as I think I should_.

Comment: Very nice this is what im trying to say... bwahaha. Thx very much.

Comment: 'Probably not as much as I think I should.' sounds illogical to my ears, containing two modal devices. 'Probably not as much as I should.' contains a sensible modal hedging.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Do you exercise?
A: Not as much as I should

*Explanation: I don't have a formal explanation, however this is the briefest way in my view to indicate that you should be exercising more than you are currently exercising. It also indicates in a succinct manner that you know you should be exercising more, etc. You don't need to say "I thought" because the phrase "I should" already implies you are thinking about it.*

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained what correction you made to the original, and why.

Comment: No worries, I'll edit it.

Comment: Guys, I have already got what I'm trying to say. Anyway, is ''Probably not as much as I think I should'' a fix phrase?

Comment: Hi John, that is not correct, or unnecessary, it should be, "Probably not as much as I should". As above, you don't need to say "I think", it is implied that you are already thinking about it :)

Comment: Oh... I see. It sounds more correct SaltySub. Ok, so its 'probably not as much as i should' then. Is this a set/fix phrase?

Comment: Yes that phrase is fine and commonly used.